# Porque é que criação do model não me cria a migration?

Tags: laravel, mvc, laravel-5

Estou a começar no Laravel 5 e a seguir [este tutorial](http://blog.butecopensource.org/laravel-5-do-comeco-ao-fim-parte-3/).

Ao criar o *model*

```
php artisan make:model Tarefa
```

ele não me cria a *migration* em `database/migrations/` como seria suposto, alguém sabe o motivo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação do Laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent), você precisa passar o argumento `--migration` ou `-m` nesse comando:

> If you would like to generate a database migration when you generate the model, you may use the `--migration` or `-m` option:
>
> ```
> php artisan make:model User --migration
>
> php artisan make:model User -m
> ```

Dessa forma a migration será criada.

Comment: É o mal de ir ver primeiro ao SOen e não ir à documentação oficial. Obrigado.